# dplyr - Evaluation error: argument "n" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, filter, arguments, dplyr

UPDATE: i uninstalled and reinstalled dplyr and now its working fine. Not sure why this happens

Often times when I'm using dplyr functions I get this error, "Evaluation error: argument "n" is missing, with no default."

It happens for random operations I use inside dplyr but I'll show a simple one I'm getting with the mutate function. Analyzing the years baseball players played in a df called `hof`, I have a "From" column which is their first year, and a "To" column which is their last year (neither column has any missing values and both are numeric). I'm using mutate to find their middle year

*Note: I'm sure there are other ways to do this without dplyr but I want to solve this issue since it happens to me often with filter as well

I've made sure commas, parenthesis, and all words are used correctly. I've also tried calling the function directly like dplyr::mutate

```
hof <- hof %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(MidCareer = (From + To) / 2)
```

### And the error message

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument "n" is missing, with no default.
```